# Ensemble of Artificial Neural Networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, ensemble-learning

I would like to predict the probabilities of 7 classes: $$C = {c_1, ...., c_7}$$ I do not have a single model which outputs the 7 probabilities, but I have several mini-models pre-trained on different subsets of C (subsets can be disjoint or overlap).

For example:

- $M_1$ trained on classes ${1, 3, 4}$
- $M_2$ trained on classes ${3, 5, 6}$
- $M_3$ trained on classes ${2, 5, 7}$
- ...

How can I average the results meaningfully in order to get the prediction of the 7 classes?

**Further info:** I know the size of the dataset and the number of examples of each class

Comment: Train additional layers on top of concatenation of your minimodels output?

Comment: What's stopping you from aggregating your data and training a single model on all classes?

Comment: @Dims That is what I did at the end. With a single additional layer and a softmax I got 40% accuracy. Is it ok, since the random choice has probability of about 14% to be correct?

Comment: @Bar I wanted to avoid re-training since the dataset has about 35k images of 48x48 gray-scale pixels. But surely is a possibility. I eventually did as Dim suggested. Do you think I could get better results with your approach?

Comment: Only way to know is if you try it out.